# Why Meteor.user and Meteor.userId differ?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have an interceptor:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
        console.log("lets login");
        Router.go("login");
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
}, {
    except: ['login', 'signup']
});
```

It works very well, until I replace the !Meteor.userId() for Meteor.user(). It seems that .user when refreshing the page goes undefined and redirect it to my login page. My login router also verifies .user and here it is right.

Why this difference?

Comment: See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386208/meteor-logout-causes-helper-to-rerun).

Comment: Meteor.userId() returns current user id and Meteor.user() returns whole object

Comment: @Nakib I know, but this is not the problem. My if !Meteor.user() verifies objects too, but it always come undefined after refresh.

Comment: @DavidWeldon your answer makes sense, but is this a bug?

Comment: Nope. You just want the reactive variable that gets updated first, and the mechanics of the login + publish process make `Meteor.user()` take much longer to have the correct information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's true, Meteor.userId() returns the id while Meteor.user() returns the object.

However, returning an object (*Meteor.user()*) takes more time than just returning an ID, due to the asynchronous issue, by the time the script is checking **if (!Meteor.user()) {...}**, *Meteor.user()* has not been processed and returned yet!

As a result, there are several ways to due with that asynchronous issue (for example, in Meteor/React application, we may have something like *subscribe*, and wait until the *handle* is *ready*)